# What's the noun for an animal's personality?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

When you describe a cat or dog's personality, what's the noun for it? "My cat has this personality of ..." just sounds wrong.

Comment: This will likely depend on what the ellipsis represents. Can you provide one or two specific examples of what you want to communicate?

Comment: @ChrisSchiffhauer, I won't be able to provide an example. Out of nowhere I had this thought today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Veterinary behaviorists would call this *temperament*.

*Saunders Comprehensive Veterinary Dictionary*, 2nd edition, defines it as:

> the peculiar behavioral character and mental cast of an animal.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

- Tendency?
- Predilection?
- Disposition?
- Temperament?

Answer (score 2):

"Personality" is the right word.  Also, they can be personable, and you can impersonate animals too.